# Sql: display just the changed data in each row

Tags: sql, sql-server, report, ms-access-2007

I would like to know how can I have results like below in Access (sql or reports) or with SQL SERVER?

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| ID    |  Name  |  Job        |  Date        |  Hobby       |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 1     |  Alex  |  carpenter  |  12/02/2006  |  basketball  |
| 1     |        |             |              |  baseball    |
| 2     |  Lara  |  dancer     |  06/07/2015  |  running     |
| 2     |        |             |              |  cooking     |
| 2     |        |             |              |  swimming    |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

The results that i have after executing my query are for example:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| ID    |  Name  |  Job        |  Date        |  Hobby       |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 1     |  Alex  |  carpenter  |  12/02/2006  |  basketball  |
| 1     |  Alex  |  carpenter  |  12/02/2006  |  baseball    |
| 2     |  Lara  |  dancer     |  06/07/2015  |  running     |
| 2     |  Lara  |  dancer     |  06/07/2015  |  cooking     |
| 2     |  Lara  |  dancer     |  06/07/2015  |  swimming    |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

The idea here is to always keep the first row as it is, but the following ones with the same ID should contain just the ID and the data that change, as shown in the example above.

The query here is not so important because I just want to have a particular display of the results.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Show your current query . Also, how do you decide which value will still be with data and which are nulls?

Comment: The idea is to delete in each row all the data that is the same in the previous ones with the same ID.

Comment: Again, edit your question and add you current query. Why do you delete LARA cooking and swimming, and not running? how do you decide? the date and ID are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it appears you are trying to remove the duplicate rows for the 'Name', 'Job', and 'Date' fields and have them displayed only for the first row in each combination.

To accomplish this, you can try the below:

1. Have your data in a temporary table
2. Apply the partition by clause for finding the Rank for each combination (of name, job, date fields) and add that as an additional column in the temporary table
3. update the temporary table to blank out the name, job, date fields where the rank value is > 1, and select the columns you need. This should make your table look like the one you had mentioned

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you explain how to do the second step please ? imagine we have 30 columns.

Comment: Hi Javier, you can use the below query (assuming the temp table you have created in step one is #temp2): 
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) ROW_NO, * INTO #TEMP3 FROM #TEMP2

Comment: The problem with this solution is that we know in advance which columns will change. But in my case, all columns can change. For example the same person can have more than one job and just one hobby, etc.

Comment: In that case, you would need to use the actual columns rather than the ID column for partitioning.

Comment: Thank you AJJ. Your answer helped me to display the result as i wished.